# OrchardCore loading within Program.cs, is it possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, orchardcore

All the examples of OrchardCore show embedding within the startup.cs file but is there a way to load it earlier within the Program.cs?  I'm trying to setup a module for Serilog so I can just drop it into my projects but maybe this isn't even possible, I don't know.

Comment: Startup.cs is pretty early in the bootstrapping process.  Why do you want to start things sooner?  What will be the benefit of running OrchardCore (whatever that is) before most of the project has been initialised?

Comment: @Neil Serilog is suggested to be loaded in the program.cs so that you can log issues starting your host.

Comment: Even in core? Logging generally hasn't even been configured until after ConfigureServices has run.

Comment: @Helzgate Show some code to demonstrate the current situation and the desired solution in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  so that we get a better understanding of the problem

Comment: @Nkosi there is nothing to show.  If you take a blank c# project, how to you load OrchardCore within the program.cs.  I'm not talking about using it for CMS, just for module loading as in [this Visual Studio video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrQaKv2mxFU&t=2s)

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer on OrchardCore's github repo found [here](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/blob/0326e2a19fb49b16b53f1ef357be06b9cc8679bf/src/OrchardCore/OrchardCore.Logging.Serilog/readme.md)

### EDIT

Later I realized this didn't really answer my question but oh well.  Leaving this answer here in case it fits someone's needs.

Here is the setup:

#### add a reference to OrchardCore.Logging.Serilog

#### add serilog configuration in appsettings.json

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Override": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "System": "Error"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss}|{TenantName}|{RequestId}|{SourceContext}|{Level:u3}|{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": {
          "pathFormat": "app_data/logs/orchard-log-{Date}.txt",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff}|{TenantName}|{RequestId}|{SourceContext}|{Level:u3}|{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

#### Modify program.cs to use Serilog

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
        => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilogWeb()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

#### Modify startup.cs to include TenantName in LogContext

```
using OrchardCore.Logging;

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseOrchardCore(c => c.UseSerilogTenantNameLoggingMiddleware());
}
```